# Rows disappearing from results when ordered

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I must do the following query:

```
select users.Name, users.ProfilePictureUrl, commons.Name, provinces.Name, GetAge(users.Birthday) as Age, users.LastOnline,
   search_scores.SocialAccountPresent, search_scores.UnansweredMessages, search_scores.WeightedRecentMessages
from users  
inner join search_scores on users.ID = search_scores.UserID  
inner join commons on commons.ID = users.CommonID  
inner join provinces on provinces.ID = commons.ProvinceID  
where (ProfileValid = 1)
order by SocialAccountPresent desc, UnansweredMessages asc, WeightedRecentMessages asc
```

However, the result set is empty, but **only** if I include the order clause. When order-by is omitted, all results are showed correctly... There are two rows in the result set, and for all of them SocialAccountPresent = 1, UnansweredMessages = 0 and WeightedRecentMessages = 0.

I am puzzled... suggestions?

Comment: A syntactically correct `order by` clause does not affect the contents of the rows being returned.  It only affects their order.  Something else is likely to be the problem.

Comment: On the order hand, a syntactically **incorrect** order by isn't even parsed.

Comment: As they said, the order by should not change anything.  But as a general troubleshooting practice, if you are getting dropped rows, try changing your inner joins to LEFT JOINs.  I can't tell from which table the "ProfileValid" column in your filter is originating (assuming "users", in which case, the left joins should loosen things up).  If you suddenly see results, then you may have cases of  where one of the later joined tables doesn't have a record for the given user/search_score/common.

Comment: Yeah, that was the issue. Weird indeed, but it works with a left join.

Comment: You should answer, so I can mark this as resolved :p